# ExecuteStreamCommand Hangs when executing Shell Script (that execute Hive)

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an flow that fetches a file, extract texts, and runs a shell script which in turn runs a hive script. (I am just pulling a date from the file and passing it as -hivevar). My shell script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
endDate=$1

CONNECT="jdbc:hive2://master2:10000/default"

beeline -u "$CONNECT" -n root -hivevar endDate="$endDate" -f /pathToScript/Hive_scipt.hql
```

The hive script completes and data is inserted into my table but the ExecuteStreamCommand stays running (1 stays at the top corner) indefinitely and I have to restart nifi.. (is there a better way to handle this?).

I've noticed a few things:

- If I reduce the size of the query (my hive query is a number of union's) the ExecuteStreamCommand wont hang.
- When the job hangs, the AM on Resource Manager stays Running for quite some time ~10 min. Sort of like when you create a Hive CLI Tez Session with 1 container. When i reduce the query size and the job doesn't hang the AM goes to finish state right away.
  -Running the full query or the script manually via command line works fine.
- Behavior is not consistent. Sometimes it wont hang, sometimes it will...(most of the time it will..)

Any ideas? Couldn't find anything in app.log or application log

Answer (score 0):

When you run that from the command-line, does it generate lots of output (on either/both standard out and/or standard error), such as the Tez/MR progress?

Try beeline with the --silent=true option (unless you really need the output for some reason), or the (albeit deprecated) "hive" client with -S. If the output is the problem, this should alleviate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your case could be related to the issue I solved in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5024.

If your script is logging enough to stderr (I can reproduce the bug with 1mb but it could be less) then the unix process running the hive script and the ExecuteStreamCommand processor will enter in a deadlock. The details are in the jira issue above.